# Listar com WHILE uma QUERY com 2 Joins

Tags: php, mysql, query

Estou tentando fazer um relatório unindo 3 tabelas. Porém não esta sendo gerada a tabela. A query funciona no PHPMYADMIN, mas não no php.

Banco de Dados rodando a Query
[image: Com a Query]

Código PHP

```
        $sql = "SELECT fp_marca.marca as MarcaF, 
        fp_modelo.modelo as ModeloF,
        fp_ano.combustivel as CombustivelF,
        fp_ano.ano as AnoF,
        fp_ano.valor as ValorF 

        FROM fp_ano 

        LEFT JOIN fp_modelo  on fp_ano.codigo_modelo = fp_modelo.codigo_modelo 
        LEFT JOIN fp_marca on fp_modelo.codigo_marca = fp_marca.codigo_marca

        ORDER BY fp_ano.codigo_fipe, fp_ano.ano";

        $result = mysqli_query($sql) or die("error in query");

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr>
                    <td>" . $row['marca'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['modelo'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['combustivel'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['ano'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['valor'] . "</td>
                  </tr>";
        }
```

Resposta ao Código

```
error in query
```

Comment: Em uma consulta tu usou mysql-i- e na outra mysql. Não é isso?
$result = mysqli_query($sql) or die("error in query"); [mysqli]
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) [mysql]

Comment: Fiz a correção, a query parou de dar o erro, mas ainda não esta exibindo a lista, a página fica em branco.

Comment: Usando var_dump ele dá alguma informação?
Tenta dar um echo $row['ModeloF'] e vê se sai resultado.

Comment: Sem resultado. Página em Branco

Comment: Cara, é difícil sem ter a base de dados para testar.
Meu conhecimento não é muito grande para olhar e te dizer o que pode estar trancando.
Das duas uma: me manda as tabelas ou olha esse tutorial - http://blog.thiagobelem.net/relacionamento-de-tabelas-no-mysql